# Twitter Counter Not Showing on Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, button, twitter, count

The twitter button does not display the count in Chrome and Safari. It does however display in Firefox. 
I have tried on multiple devices, mobile, laptop, desktop and had friends try it. So I don't think it's anything related to my system. It worked fine until yesterday.
Here is the link. 
http://www.thearcticinstitute.org/2015/01/011415-TATW-2015-1.html
Same is true for any other post on the website.

Any suggestions?

Here is the button code I am using.

```
<a href="https://twitter.com/share" class="twitter-share-button" data-via="malte_humpert">Tweet</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],p=/^http:/.test(d.location)?'http':'https';if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src=p+'://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js';fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document, 'script', 'twitter-wjs');</script>
```